# iOS: Updating old application to Retina graphics (TweeJump)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, 2d-games

I'm new to the site and also iOS developing as well, but I have experience with other developing platforms.

I have been studying and playing around with the TweeJump source code and I want to update it to Retina graphics, I have made my own but I'm not sure how to implement them properly. Does doing this cut off support for non-retina iPhones?

Some of the images are in a sprite, which I'm not familiar with.

If I just change all the images to high resolution ones, what problems will arise and how can I resolve them?

Please excuse my beginner knowledge. I will really appreciate ANY help you can offer.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Updating your game to support Retina display is easy if you have the original non-rasterized (e.g vector) graphics for the images. Just export the graphics as twice as large as the SD images and append `-hd` (or `-ipadhd` for iPad) to the part of the filenames before the extension. Just make sure your app delegate calls `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] enableRetinaDisplay:YES]` and you are good to go.

> Does doing this cut off support for non-retina iPhones?

Absolutely not. As long as you retain the SD images.

> Some of the images are in a sprite, which I'm not familiar with.

You mean "spritesheet"? This is one of the situations where you need to have access to the original vector graphics for each individual sprite. Plus, you need to use a spritesheet editor in order to generate the HD version of the spritesheet. I recommend [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker).

> If I just change all the images to high resolution ones, what problems will arise and how can I resolve them?

Make sure to retain the SD versions as well. One of the problems that may arise is if you have a spritesheet with the size of larger than 1024 x 1024 for the SD version. The HD version will have size larger than 2048 x 2048 which OpenGL ES 1.1 cannot support. You would need to break the spritesheet into more pieces or convert to OpenGL ES 2.0 (i.e. convert to cocos2d-iphone 2.x).